# bloodhound not showing all data returned from remote call typeahead.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I'm using typeahed.js and bloodhound.js (with an mvc wrapper) and my remote server call is retrieving data based on details typed into a textbox.

For example, I type 'Fr' and I get three companies that start with Fr. I've checked the serverside code (c#) and I get 3 results. I've used Fiddler and checked that the browser is receiving (3 Json records) yet the typeahead suggestion only shows 2 items.

The limit in bloodhound is set to 1000 and I've switched caching off. Is this a known issue with these js libraries ?

Its basically unusable since I'm not getting an accurate representation of my actual search. I'm using the latest versions (twitter.typeahead v 0.11.11 and the version of bloodhound that's packaged with typeahead). I've spent so much time trying to figure out whats wrong with this, but I've had no luck.

I really don't want to have to rewrite parts of my app to use a different autocomplete mechanism. Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: some codes would might be helpful

Comment: I gave up with it in the end, its not really fit for purpose.  No amount of searching gave any insight into why it wouldnt work so ive implemented an alternative solution